# update PostgreSQL client library to 9.1

Tags: python, postgresql

I am installing psycopg2 using this command:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

But the output is:

> ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:2: error: #error "Psycopg requires PostgreSQL
>   client library (libpq) >= 9.1"

My pg_config version: `pg_config --version` is `PostgreSQL 8.4.20`. How to upgrade PostgreSQL client library? I am searching from Google, but no method to guide me. Python version: 3.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade pip version 7.1.2 to version 18.1 solve this problem:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Execute this command to install `psycopg2`:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: I guess that PostgreSQL client library is not installed via pip; but it is dependency for `psycopg2`, isn't it? So one could install latest `psycopg2` toolkit, without having latest PostgreSQL client lib...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to install it according to these instructions - https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/.

Comment: Multiple installations instructions on that link. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: I'm not sure why at that moment I've posted link to Red Hat distribution, but the point was not to update it from pip, but to download and install client to the machine. And the way how to do that - is up to the user.